# Grep: List 'per-file' Results

Tags: linux, shell, unix, grep

Is there any way to list 'per-file' results neatly using grep.

Something like:

```
$grep -i -r -n Search_Pattern .
```

Output:

```
file1.c:

LINE_NO: .......... Search_Pattern ....... /* Line Containing Search Pattern */
LINE_NO: .......... Search_Pattern .......
LINE_NO: .......... Search_Pattern .......
LINE_NO: .......... Search_Pattern .......

file2.c:

LINE_NO: .......... Search_Pattern .......
LINE_NO: .......... Search_Pattern .......
LINE_NO: .......... Search_Pattern .......
LINE_NO: .......... Search_Pattern .......
```

Comment: Consider trying out `ack-grep` if it's available to you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

is this what you want?

```
 $grep -i -r -n Search_Pattern .|awk -F: '$1!=f{print "\n"$1"\n";f=$1} {print $2":"$3}'
```